# Вывод значения при условии, что подобного нету в другой таблице

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Нужно вывести информацию с `db_order`, если нету ни одного повторения значения с `db_order.id` в таблице `db_ips.order_id`.

Сами таблицы:

db_ips
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

db_order
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то как то так:

```
SELECT
    db_order.*
FROM 
    db_order
    LEFT OUTER JOIN db_ips  ON db_order.id = db_ips.order_id
WHERE 
    db_ips.order_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: @ВладиславСироштан соединение таблиц работает быстрее, чем подзапросы. Пометьте ответ галкой напротив, который считает наиболее правильным.

Answer (score 4):

1й способ:

```
SELECT db_order.*
  FROM db_order
  LEFT JOIN db_ips ON db_order.id = db_ips.order_id
 WHERE db_ips.order_id IS NULL
```

2й способ:

```
SELECT *
  FROM db_order
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(select 1 from db_ips where db_order.id = db_ips.order_id)
```

3й способ:

```
SELECT *
  FROM db_order
 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT order_id FROM db_ips)
```

Скорость выполнения этих запросов может отличаться. Однозначного ответа, какой из них будет быстрее, конкретно на ваших данных, сказать сложно. Это зависит от количества записей в таблицах и количества совпадающих/отсутствующих значений.

Answer (score 3):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  db_order
WHERE
  id NOT IN (SELECT
              DISTINCT order_id
            FROM
              db_ips)
```

Comment: И вам спасибо за подсказку.