# SQL запрос к двум таблицам (одной)

Tags: sql

Есть одна таблица с полями:

- pare
- day
- aud (может быть куча дублей)

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT auditories.*
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM TRANS_min
      GROUP BY aud) auditories
  RIGHT JOIN (SELECT *
              FROM TRANS_min
              WHERE pare = 1 AND day = 6
              GROUP BY aud) paramAuditories
    ON paramAuditories.aud = auditories.aud
WHERE paramAuditories.aud IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY auditories.aud
```

**ВЫБОРКИ**

два раза делаем запрос к таблице и делаем выборку
первый раз без условия достаем список всех уникальных записей по aud
второй раз делаем такую же выборку и накладываем условие выборки по дню и номеру пары - получаем список уникальных записей по aud

**ЗАДАЧА**: достать записи из первой таблицы которых нету во второй таблице

В таблице около 2 млн записей :-)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вывод значения при условии, что подобного нету в другой таблице](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/563572/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5)

Comment: И да, конкретно в вашем случае (так как таблица всего одна и вы _хотите_ применять группировку) все гораздо проще: `SELECT *
              FROM TRANS_min
              GROUP BY aud HAVING sum( case when pare = 1 AND day = 6 then 1 else 0 end)=0`

Comment: @Mike, а как все тоже самое сделать без GROUP BY?

Comment: так вы бы определились, нужен он вам или нет, от этого же возвращаемый результат сильно зависит. Ваш вариант в вопросе с убранными group by подойдет, например. или любой из вариантов по первой ссылке

Comment: @Mike вообще мне нужно достать 4 поля из таблички, где поле aud может повторяться большое количество раз. Запросы работают правильно, но нужно как-то сгруппировать значения по aud.
DISTINCT не подходит же... вот и использую group by, но на боевом сервере стоит мускул 5.7. У него включен режим ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY и запрос не работает

Comment: ай, я понял в чем проблема...
оно делает group by, а в select у меня приходит одно aud и куча значений к другим полям.. нужно просто заюзать какую-то функцию, которая из этой кучи будет выбирать одно значение и тогда все заработает

Comment: но "_достать 4 поля из таблички_" и "_сгруппировать значения по aud_" противоречат друг другу. когда мы группируем по aud то какие значения тех 4х полей надо брать для группы максимальные/минимальные/сумму/список_через_запятую или может из какой то конкретной записи. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/599772/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-group-by-%D0%B2-mysql/599802#599802

Comment: @Mike, да, только что додумался до этого) спасибо за ссылку. То, что надо.

Comment: GROUP BY поможет

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM TRANS_min
      GROUP BY aud) auditories
WHERE auditories.aud NOT IN (SELECT aud
                             FROM TRANS_min
                             WHERE pare = 1
                             GROUP BY aud)
```

получилось решить ))

Comment: `SELECT *
      FROM TRANS_min
      GROUP BY aud` не допустимо в большинстве диалектов SQL (если конечно в таблице не единственная колонка aud), потому что все выбираемые колонки должны либо присутствовать в group by либо использоваться в агрегатных функциях. только MySQL (и то не все версии не со всеми настройками) и sqlite допускают такие вольности. И по условиям вами же данной задачи "_достать записи из первой таблицы которых нету во второй таблице_" ни одного group by не нужно в принципе