# MySql JOIN, Условие по связаной талице дублирует записи

Tags: mysql, yii2, join

Вот запрос к бд в реальном виде:

```
SELECT catalog_product.* FROM `catalog_product` 
LEFT JOIN `prop_handler_value` ON     
    `catalog_product`.`id` = `prop_handler_value`.`handler_id` 
LEFT JOIN `prop_value` ON 
    `prop_handler_value`.`value_id` = `prop_value`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `prop_object` ON 
    `prop_value`.`object_id` = `prop_object`.`id`
WHERE `prop_object`.`class`='app\\modules\\catalog\\models\\Product'
```

Есть связь ManyToMany

catalog_product(id, name)

prop_handler_value(id, handler_id, value_id)

prop_value(id, name)

Если в бд будет такая ситуация:

```
catalog_product: 
id = 1; name = 'продукт1'

prop_value: 
id = 1; name = 'Занчение1'
id = 2; name = 'Занчение2'

prop_handler_value: 
id = 1; handler_id = 1; value_id = 1
id = 2; handler_id = 1; value_id = 2
```

Т.е у продукта есть 2 значения. И мне нужно вывести продукты, в которых value_id = 1 OR 2, то запись "Продукт1" дублируется.

Проблему решает GROUP BY , но запрос делается намного медленнее. Какие есть еще варианты?

Comment: COUNT(DISTINCT `catalog_product`.`id`)?

Comment: Вместо left join использовать EXISTS. примерно как тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/563604/194569 (2й способ) только убрать NOT

Comment: *мне нужно вывести продукты* А судя по тексту запроса, Вам нужно их (?) количество.

Comment: @Akina , не тот запрос с лога скопировал. Но суть вопроса это не меняет.

Comment: *не тот запрос с лога скопировал.* - ну так откорректируйте вопрос!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый день.
Если вам вам нужны продукты, то `COUNT` убираем.
Если вы накладываете условие на последнюю таблицу в связке джоинов, то `LEFT JOIN` тут тоже лишний.

В результате:

Вариант, предложенный @Zufir, будет выглядеть примерно так

```
SELECT DISTINCT `catalog_product`.`id FROM `catalog_product` 
JOIN `prop_handler_value` ON     
    `catalog_product`.`id` = `prop_handler_value`.`handler_id` 
JOIN `prop_value` ON 
    `prop_handler_value`.`value_id` = `prop_value`.`id` 
JOIN `prop_object` ON 
    `prop_value`.`object_id` = `prop_object`.`id`
WHERE `prop_object`.`class`='app\\modules\\catalog\\models\\Product'
```

Вариант, предложенный @Mike, будет выглядеть примерно так

```
SELECT `catalog_product`.`id FROM `catalog_product` 
WHERE EXIST (SELECT 1 FROM `prop_handler_value` 
JOIN `prop_value` ON 
    `prop_handler_value`.`value_id` = `prop_value`.`id` 
JOIN `prop_object` ON 
    `prop_value`.`object_id` = `prop_object`.`id`
WHERE `prop_object`.`class`='app\\modules\\catalog\\models\\Product'
AND `catalog_product`.`id` = `prop_handler_value`.`handler_id`)
```

Вариант с `GROUP BY` вы нашли сами. Выбирайте, какой из этих вариантов лучше подходит к вашей структуре.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Вариант с EXIST уже протестировал - на 20% быстрее чем groupBy,  оперировал небольшим количеством записей. Думаю DISTINCT будет оптимальней всего, посмотрим что скажут цифры.