# SQL запрос на вывод не связанных данных

Tags: sql, select

Здравствуйте возникла проблема с написанием SQL запроса(Использую СУБД SQLite). Имею таблицы Classes(Класс) и Teachers(Учителя). И мне нужно вывести учителей который не связаны с классом, т.е. которые не являются классным руководителем класса.

Таблица classes:

```
Create  TABLE classes(
[id] integer PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE NOT NULL,
[name] varchar(15) NOT NULL,
[id_teacher] integer NOT NULL
);
```

Таблица teachers:

```
Create  TABLE teachers(
[id] integer PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE NOT NULL,
[name] varchar(150) NOT NULL,
[number] varchar(15),
[address] varchar(200) NOT NULL,
[date_birth] datetime NOT NULL,
[id_predmet] integer REFERENCES [predmets] ([id]) On Delete NO ACTION On Update NO ACTION
);
```

Мог бы изменить связи, но тогда будет сложна добираться до учителя класса из прилоежения, через запрос для класса.

Comment: Советую познакомиться с SQL Style Guide и следовать ему всегда и везде.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вывод значения при условии, что подобного нету в другой таблице](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/563572/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно [внешнее соединение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)

```
select
  t.*
from teachers t
left outer join classes c
  on c.id_teacher = t.id
where c.id_teacher is null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант :

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM teachers
WHERE id NOT IN (select id_teacher from classes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще можно [так](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/exists.php):

```
SELECT *
FROM teachers
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM classes
              WHERE teachers.id = classes.id_teacher);
```

По опыту использования этой инструкции в Access и MS SQL могу сказать, что в некоторых случаях она быстрее `LEFT JOIN`