# Оптимизировать запрос SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Добрый день. 
Есть две таблицы, в каждой есть по колонке большим количеством строк(1.5 млн и 4 млн). Необходимо написать запрос, который выводит уникальные значения колонки первой таблицы, которых нет в колонке второй таблицы.

Я написала следующий запрос:

```
select column1 from Table1 where column1  not in (select column2 from  Table2)
```

Запрос выполнялся больше 17ч и безрезультатно. При этом sql management studio дико подвисает. При принудительной остановке вышла ошибка: object reference not set to an instance of an object sql.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что можно сделать в таком  случае.

Comment: вместо in пробовали использовать join?

Comment: Какой тип у вашей колонки, возможно или создание индекса по ней?

Comment: попробуйте отсюда https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/563604/194569 1й вариант. посмотрите план выполнения. может стоит попробовать 2й вариант, но тогда на поле column2 во второй таблице должен быть индекс

Comment: SELECT t1.column1 FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.column1 = t2.column2 WHERE t2.column2 IS NULL; - что-то типа такого

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете получить искомые данные тремя разными способами:

1. Используя `IN`, как в Вашем примере, только для уникальности нужен `DISTINCT`:

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT column1 
   FROM Table1 
   WHERE column1  NOT IN (
       SELECT column2 
       FROM  Table2
   )
   ```
2. Используя `LEFT JOIN`:

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT column1 
   FROM Table1 t1
       LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.column1 = t2.column2
   WHERE t2.KeyColumn IS NULL
   ```
3. Используя EXCEPT

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT column1
   FROM Table1
   EXCEPT
   SELECT column2
   FROM Table2
   ```

Для улучшения производительности этих запросов нужно создать индексы по полям Table1.column1 и Table2.column2.

Answer (score 1):

1. Желательно построить/проверить индекс для `Column1` таблицы `Table1` и `Column2` таблицы `Table2`.
2. Изменить текст запроса:

   `SELECT 
       DISTINCT Table1
   FROM 
       Table1
   WHERE 
       NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM Table2
                   WHERE Table1.Table1 = Table2.Column2)`