# Добавление только уникальных записей из 1 таблицы во вторую MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Нашел в гугле пример по своему вопросу, попытался повторить, но получаю

> Affected rows: 0
>   Time: 0s

Т.е. ничего не добавляется в таблицу history из таблицы coins_info.

```
INSERT INTO history (coin_name, symbol, date_load_stats, price_usd, price_btc, url_curr_loaded) 
SELECT coins_info.`name`, symbol, date_last_load, price_usd, price_btc, url_loaded 
FROM coins_info 
WHERE (date_last_load>DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -15 MINUTE)) 
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT symbol, date_load_stats, url_curr_loaded 
      FROM history 
      GROUP BY symbol, date_load_stats, url_curr_loaded);
```

Записи, новее 15 минут естественно в таблице имеются. Опишу задачу подробнее, на случай если из запроса ничего не понятно:
Скрипт делает регулярный UPDATE данных в таблицу coins_info, нужно из этой таблицы периодически брать все данные, отсутствующие в таблице history и добавлять все записи в нее. Просто инсертнуть все данные из coins_info в history не проблема, но не хочется разводить там кучу дублирующихся записей, так как в coins_info запись может за указанный промежуток и не обновиться, тогда получим в coins_info 2 абсолютно одинаковые записи. В общем заковырка в том что нужно инсертить только записи, которых нету в таблице hystory, что по идее и должен делать запрос выше, по крайней мере из примера я понял именно это. Но что-то в нем не так и он не добавляет ни 1 записи. Кто может поправить запрос, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: not exists в вашем запросе всегда дает false так как он никак не связан с внешним запросом (должны присутствовать условия соединения с колонками из внешней части запроса) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/563572/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5/563604#563604

Comment: Спасибо, добавил WHERE history.date_load_stats = coins_info.date_last_load в условие отбора, все заработало! :)